# Use OpenFileDialog Read FileName But read ""

Tags: c#, wpf

In my `WpfAPP` I use a button to select file to read the `fileName` the code is

```
        private void Select_File(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog()
            {
                Filter = "|*.csv;*.xls;*.xlsx",
                Title = "Read File",
                Multiselect = false
            };
            bool? res = ofd.ShowDialog();
            if (res != null && res.Value)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("==========================");
                string strOpenFile = ofd.FileName;
                Debug.WriteLine(strOpenFile);
            }
        }
```

but the fileName is ""
How to read the `fileName` successfully?

[image]

Comment: What exact line are you on in the debugger when you take that screenshot?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

your filter syntax is wrong. Try this

```
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();           
            ofd.Filter = "CSV files (*.csv)|*.csv|Excel (*.xls)|*.xls";
            ofd.Title = "Read File";
            ofd.Multiselect = false;
            
            bool? res = ofd.ShowDialog();
           
            if (res != null && res.Value)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("==========================");
                string strOpenFile = ofd.FileName;
                Debug.WriteLine(strOpenFile);
            }
```

Comment: thanks! but why wrong syntax  made this? is is work in winform

Comment: @AmitVerma I didn't vote, but this was very likely because you didn't add any explaining text. My suggestion: note OPs comment asking for clarification, then edit your answer to give more context. That should help!

Comment: @ModusTollens Thanks. I will take care from next time.